# Cant get socket identity when using CZMQ's zsock_new_stream

Tags: c, linux, zeromq

Why can't I get the Identity of the socket created via zsock_new_stream? zmq_getsockopt returns -1.

```
zsock_t *socket = zsock_new_stream("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

uint8_t id [256];
size_t id_size = 256;

int rc = zmq_getsockopt (socket, ZMQ_IDENTITY, id, &id_size);
assert(rc == 0);
```

Using the old deprecated zsocket works fine, see below:

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new();
void *sock = zsocket_new(ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
int rc = zsocket_connect(sock, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

uint8_t id [256];
size_t id_size = 256;

int rc = zmq_getsockopt (socket, ZMQ_IDENTITY, id, &id_size);
assert (rc == 0);
```

Does an example exist that uses zsock_new_stream that works?

Comment: Maybe you should check *why* `zmq_getsockopt` returns `-1`? There must be something similar to `errno` or a function to get the error from the last failed function.

Comment: Ok I checked the errno. And it says "socket operation on non socket". How can this be? The czmq api states that zsock_new_stream creates a stream socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no working example because the identity property is ignored for STREAM sockets. The czmq implementation follows the [ZMTP v3 protocole](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:37/ZMTP).

Quote, regarding the identity property:

> "A REQ, DEALER, or ROUTER peer connecting to a ROUTER MAY announce its identity, which is used as an addressing mechanism by the ROUTER socket. For all other socket types, the Identity property shall be ignored."

But you can always send an id from a client peer to a server through multipart messages, where your id is in the first frame of the message. On the other side, getting the id is just a matter of reading the first frame of the received message.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have been doing to get around it. On connection, the client receives a message consisting of an id frame and zero frame. So I just append that frame to any messages I send.

Answer (score 1):

The "socket operation on non socket" error occurs because you are confusing the two separate concepts of the CZMQ zsock_t socket object and the underlying ZeroMQ socket. You can access the latter using the zsock_resolve() function, so the following works (at least in the sense that it returns successfully and populates the id and id_size variables):

```
int rc = zmq_getsockopt (zsock_resolve(socket), ZMQ_IDENTITY, id, &id_size);
```

I suspect the ZMTP specification is not relevant here since STREAM sockets (by definition) do not implement the ZMTP protocol. Having said that, I haven't used STREAM sockets myself, so I don't know if this approach works in practice.